# Why can't clang++ on Ubuntu 14.04 find <iostream>

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, clang++

I am compiling this program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

}
```

This command

```
g++ -c hello_world.cpp
```

works.

This command

```
clang++ -c hello_world.cpp
```

gives this error:

```
hello_world.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
#include <iostream>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

Doing:

```
clang++ -c hello_world.cpp -v
```

gives:

```
Ubuntu clang version 3.4-1ubuntu3 (tags/RELEASE_34/final) (based on LLVM 3.4)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8.4
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.9
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.9.1
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8.4
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9.1
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.8.4
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.9
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.9.1
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8.4
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9.1
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9
 "/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-pc-linux-gnu -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -main-file-name hello_world.cpp -mrelocation-model static -mdisable-fp-elim -fmath-errno -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -munwind-tables -fuse-init-array -target-cpu x86-64 -target-linker-version 2.24 -v -coverage-file /home/user/code/cpp/StackOverflow_questions/hello_world.o -resource-dir /usr/bin/../lib/clang/3.4 -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../include/c++ -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../include/c++/x86_64-linux-gnu -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../include/c++/backward -internal-isystem /usr/local/include -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/clang/3.4/include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -internal-externc-isystem /include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /home/user/code/cpp/StackOverflow_questions -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 202 -mstackrealign -fobjc-runtime=gcc -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fdiagnostics-show-option -vectorize-slp -o hello_world.o -x c++ hello_world.cpp
clang -cc1 version 3.4 based upon LLVM 3.4 default target x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../include/c++/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../include/c++/backward"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../include/c++
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/bin/../lib/clang/3.4/include
 /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
hello_world.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
#include <iostream>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

clang++ is talking about using gcc 4.9 stuff, but if I do:

g++ --version

it outputs:

```
g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE
```

This is where iostream is located on my machine:

```
/usr/share/doc/fp-docs/2.6.2/fcl/iostream
/usr/include/boost/tr1/tr1/iostream
/usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seeing as how clang++ was keen on using  g++ 4.9 files, I decided to install g++ 4.9

ubuntu does not have 4.9 as part of it's normal "sudo apt-get install g++". They are still on 4.8.  (not sure what put the gcc 4.9 (but apparently not g++ 4.9) stuff on my system).

I found out that I could install g++ 4.9 by doing:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install g++-4.9
```

After these commands were issued, clang++  was able to find <iostream>.

Comment: You probably already had gcc-4.9 installed (but not g++-4.9). Clang always chooses the highest available gcc installation, that's why clang didn't find the headers. Uninstalling gcc-4.9 would probably have helped too.

Comment: @Thomas I don't object to clang choosing the highest available gcc installation. But I don't see how guys smart enough to write a compiler would have clang++ choose the highest available gcc installation. I didn't want to uninstall gcc 4.9 because I am not sure what installed it. I have only installed "gcc go" and a gcc package to do Objective-C and Objective-C++ so I don't think it was me. .They both came from the standard Ubuntu repository which has 4.8.4 as the latest.

Comment: Look at your log output, my comment is indeed right (`/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../include/c++`). Clang and clang++ share the same header search logic, it's just one symlinked binary. You can override the default search path with `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` and or `--gcc-toolchain`.

Comment: @Thomas I didn't say your logic was incorrect. I said the clang++ developers' search logic was incorrect.  Or, another way to put it is it is incorrect for clang++ and clang to share the same header search logic. Thanks for the override options.

Comment: Probably not, it's the best for both to target the same GCC version. Having clang and clang++ target different GCC versions could cause incompatibilities (different libgcc versions, etc.).

Comment: @Thomas If clang++ needs to have the same versions of gcc software libraries as clang, then if it finds a version of gcc without g++ it needs to abort and give an error message. clang++ giving an error message of "can't find iostream" is amateurish when the files exist on the machine.

Comment: If you would know how a compiler driver works, then you wouldn't call this amateurish. The Clang driver is super complicated and it needs a lot of effort to have a compiler to find those headers on lots of different distrubutions, where every distribution is doing their own packaging madness. Especially Ubuntu, they are messing clang totally up, not even `-flto` is working there due to their weird packaging. And if you have 4.9 stuff /usr/lib while gcc 4.9 isn't even provided as a package, then this clearly an Ubuntu issue.

Comment: Using the same gcc version for both, clang and clang++ is the correct thing to do, if you really need to, then you can still override it. The error message isn't amateurish either, a compiler doesn't know (without stupid quirks) if this is a C++ standard header or not.

Comment: Erroring when g++ isn't found would be wrong too, one could still provide the C++ standard library include paths via `-I`, `-cxx-isystem` etc.

Comment: @Thomas It probably isn't right to call it amateurish. A beginning amateur programmer could test whether or not the directory where it expects to find iostream and family, exists, and not blindly assume that directory must exist and must have what it wants. It is better termed slipshod programming. A professional programmer would not provide the error when the directory with the headers was explicitly provided.  That 4.9 gcc could have come from a non-Ubuntu repository which I had to use to install a few other pieces of software like one that tries to let you use latest Flash via Wine.

Comment: Clang does not blindy add that path, it's probably a fallback option to give you a good hint where the headers would be assumed to be. You can see all the `stat()`ing clang is doing with strace, i.e. `strace clang++ test.cpp`. "A professional programmer would not provide the error when the directory with the headers was explicitly provided. " Like I already said, clang does not know whether a specific include header is a C++ standard header or not, and `-I` could also be a C include path, etc. Erroring there could cause a lot of troubles. Clang isn't a noob tool.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82489/discussion-between-scooter-and-thomas).

Answer (score -2):

Try to install these packages,

```
sudo yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
sudo yum install libstdc++-static.x86_64 compat-libstdc++-33.x86_64
```

I have had this problem and it was solved installing these packages.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You must be using Red Hat, CentOS, or other rpm package system. On Ubuntu they use "apt-get" instead of "yum". apt-get didn't like the "groupinstall" option.